# Animating elements with react-spring usesprings hook

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, react-three-fiber

Trying to animate a bunch of objects to their positions, and useSpring works for me (for single element), but useSprings is not for 3 objects.

Here is demo (mousedown red ball):
https://codesandbox.io/s/try-to-do-zgit5?file=/src/App.js:1254-1857

Here is code:

```js
  // working for me
  const { z } = useSpring({
    from: { z: 0 },
    to: { z: mousedown ? 0 : -0.5 }
  })
  // not working with state change
  // although working with a 
  // loop: { reverse: true, delay: 0 },
  // but not accounting state changes
  const [springs] = useSprings(3, (i) => ({
    from: { x: 0, y: i * 2 - 2 },
    to: { x: mousedown ? 0.5 : -0.5, y: i * 2 - 2 + 1 },
  }))
```

and the elements:

```js
// works
<a.mesh position-z={z} 
    onPointerDown={(e) => setMousedown(true)} 
    onPointerUp={(e) => setMousedown(false)}>...</a.mesh>

// not changing positions with state
{springs.map(({ x, y }, index) => (
     <a.mesh position-x={x} position-y={y} key={`0${index}`}>...</a.mesh>
))}
```

As im new to react-spring, this might be a ridiculous simple problem, but im just stuck with this myself now

Comment: is this what you need? https://codesandbox.io/s/try-to-do-forked-gwy21?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes exactly! you can add your answer, i wil mark that one as correct, added my comment so far.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanx to Paul Henschel in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/try-to-do-forked-gwy21?file=/src/App.js , addition of [mousedown] dependency parameter to `useSprings` hook was needed.